# Mouse double click is not opening data files with the correct application

Tags: plugins

When I installed Apache openoffice software successfully and with the help of gnome package I created a short launchers of openoffice the icon is working. I open a scalc or writer and save a data file but when I double click the file direct it does not open the application.  I tried several times.

Answer (score 0):

To set the application that opens by default for a file in Ubuntu 12.04, **right-click** on the file, choose **Properties**, click the **Open With** tab, and select your preferred application. If your preferred application is not listed, click the Show other applications button.

Your question was hard for me to understand. I hope I gave you the information you need.